# Availability of Playn support libraries and engines

Tags: playn

[This](http://playn-2011.appspot.com/slides/index.html#16) slide in a recent playn presentation shows clearly the differentiation between playn Core API, and third party libs and engines.  I wish to re-implement as little as possible, is there an obvious method to source these libs and engines that will combine with playn?

The playn-jbox2d.jar used in the showcase, I assume this a specific build of the java box 2d lib for playn?  Will similar manual porting be required for other libraries or can e.g. Android libs be easily reused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PlayN is a completely different API than Android, so you cannot use an Android game development library with PlayN. Higher level libraries are already being written for PlayN (for example, http://github.com/threerings/flashbang-playn), but since the platform is relatively new, not as many such libraries exist as for Android directly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize that while you write in java that is used by all platforms, the method of how that java is compiled to the different platform is widely different (Android SDK for Android, GWT for html etc). If you have a library that uses only a subset of java that is supported on each compilation path for evey platform you should be able to use it out of the box but this is not very likely.